# Getting error while parsing an XML 1.1 document with Stax parser

Tags: java, xpath, stax

I am trying to parse Burp Suite XML export. I have used Stax parser and XPath parser. But I am getting

```
Location: /py/message/viewBill.pt [id parameter]]]></location>
<severity>High</severity>
<confidence>Certain</confidence>
<issueBackground><![CDATA[Reflected 
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[66,2357]
Message: The element type "location" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "< /location>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:604)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:83)
```

error all the time. Although there is an end-tag, parser cannot find it. My code is:

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventReader eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(str));

while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

    switch (event.getEventType()) {

        case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
            StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
            String qName = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(ISSUES)) {
                issues = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(ISSUE)) {
                issue = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(NAME)) {
                name = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(HOST)) {
                host = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(PATH)) {
                path = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(LOCATION)) {
                location = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(SEVERITY)) {
                severity = true;
            }
            break;

        case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
            Characters characters = event.asCharacters();
            if (name) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + characters.getData());
                name = false;
            } else if (host) {
                System.out.println("Host: " + characters.getData());
                host = false;
            } else if (path) {
                System.out.println("Path: " + characters.getData());
                path = false;
            } else if (location) {
                System.out.println("Location: " + characters.getData());
                location = false;
            } else if (severity) {
                System.out.println("severity: " + characters.getData());
                severity = false;
            }
            break;

        case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
            EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
            String endElementName = endElement.getName().getLocalPart();

            if (endElementName.equalsIgnoreCase(ISSUE)) {
                issue = false;
            } else if (endElementName.equalsIgnoreCase(NAME)) {
                name = false;
            } else if (endElementName.equalsIgnoreCase(HOST)) {
                host = false;
            } else if (endElementName.equalsIgnoreCase(PATH)) {
                path = false;
            } else if (endElementName.equalsIgnoreCase(LOCATION)) {
                location = false;
            } 
            break;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to parse the report that I found on https://github.com/mtesauro/parse-tools/blob/master/examples/brief-burp-export.xml .

Can someone give some advice ?

Comment: Which stax parser are you using? My guess is that it doesn't support XML 1.1. Have you tried [xerces](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/)?

Comment: @ArvidHeise I am using xerces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that it's a bug in the XML parser. Specifically, I suspect it hasn't recognized `]]]>` on line 63 as terminating the CDATA section, so it carries on thinking it's in CDATA until the `]]>` at the end of line 66, at which point it found the end tag `</issueBackground>` where it was looking for `</location>`. Raise a ticket with the suppliers of the XML parser, or switch to one that works.

Answer (score 0):

I found some examples parse Burp Export with CSS. Than I found [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) for CSS parsing in Java. It is a bit complicated but works well.

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(str);
Elements allElements = document.getAllElements();

for (Element element : allElements) {
    String tagName = element.tagName();
    String text = element.text();
    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
        System.out.println("name " + text);
    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("host")) {
        System.out.println("host " + text);
        System.out.println("ip " + element.attr("ip"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. After spending some time on searching online, I have found below solution

Since the xml value has CDATA, event type will be XMLEvent.CDATA and not XMLEvent.CHARACTERS

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/events/XMLEvent.html
- https://github.com/dturanski/stax-xml-parser/blob/master/src/main/java/staxparser/xml/CDataContentExtractor.java

```
Switch(reader.hasNext()) {
case TAG:
    eventType = reader.next();
    if (eventType == XMLEvent.CDATA || eventType == XMLEvent.CHARACTERS) {
        System.out.println(reader.getText());
    }
    break;
........
}
```

Also I have added below dependency. I am not sure how this dependency helping but without this dependency we will get same exception mentioned above.

But after adding this dependency issue got resolved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.woodstox/woodstox-core/5.0.0